# PrivateKeyGenerated by OpenSSL to RSACRTPrivateKey object

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, bouncycastle, chinese-remainder-theorem

there is a privateKey file in PEM format generated by following Openssl command to generate a `.csr`.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out %~dp0\req.csr -keyout %~dp0\..\private.key -sha256 -config %~dp0\..\cfg.cfg
```

Now, id like to get a chinese remainder theorem - key object out of that file.
But i am not successfull unitl now.
So maybe you can give me a helping hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want a BC-only (LWAPI?) solution, or if you'll take JCE which can use *either* Sun or BC provider. If the latter:

RSA keypairs generated and written by openssl are always in CRT form unless you work hard to prevent it, and `req` doesn't. For openssl 1.0.0+ the privatekey file from `req -newkey` (and most other things) is PKCS#8 *containing* PKCS#1 CRT; in older versions it is "legacy" PKCS#1 CRT and must be reformatted into PKCS#8, most easily by **(edit)** `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in *file* -out *file* [-outform der]` (see next). PKCS#8 can be and often is encrypted, but `req -newkey -nodes` is unencrypted, and so is `pkcs8 -nocrypt`.

JCE can read **(edit)** unencrypted DER PKCS#8 containing PKCS#1 CRT (among other things). It's easier to convert PEM to DER with openssl since it's a simple commandline (especially if combined with legacy to PKCS#8 conversion, see above); then in Java:

- read the (**edit)** unencrypted PKCS#8 DER into a `byte[]` let's say `buffer` and
- pass that to `java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"[,provider]) .generatePrivate(buffer)` (or equivalent).

The result has provider-dependent type but in either case it implements interface `java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey`.

JCE doesn't do PEM itself. If you have PEM, read it, strip the BEGIN/END lines, convert remaining base64 to bytes, then proceed with JCE.